# How To Find Product Price And Product ID For A Shopify Store In Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, shopify

I am trying to customize a Shopify Theme. All the modifications are made in a single file: theme.js.liquid

I know a little about javascript. Nothing about ajax or json. I know a bit more amount about PHP. So if you could take my level in consideration in your answer that would be great.

**The problem I come across while customizing this theme is, I need to call for product id and price in that .js file.**

But I do not know how. All the google search I do lead me to pages talking about Ajax, JSON, API, and I don't know if that's relevant to my problem or not.

I know it is possible to find those values, because the .js file in the theme does it several times in some functions, they use variable names: variant.id, product, variant.price, etc.

I cannot use those because the functions aren't always running. I need to know how they get these values in the first place but I couldn't figure it out by reverse engineering the .js file.

You can find this .js file in the link below:

view-source:https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1158/6186/t/5/assets/theme.js?13926994070928300230

So my question was:

**How do I call for product id and price in that .js file.**

And if that cannot be answered, **what can I read (with my level of knowledge), to figure it out on my own?** I've googled in extensively in the last 2 days and I am lost.

Comment: Hello. Do you have access to the HTML file, and if yes, can you find those element in the file OR do they load with asyncronous functions?

Comment: I do have access to the html. I can find some div, p, span and h classes. What is an asyncronous function?

Comment: Are all the produci displayed inside the HTML or do they get loaded from an external function?

Comment: Shopify has its own template language. And product information are loaded with that.

Like this for example:
    <div class="rte product-single__description" itemprop="description">
    {{ product.description }}
     </div>

Comment: Yes, of course, that is a Common practice and is really easy to find the product id. I will post a solution later from my computer.

Comment: Kindly post a relevant section of your shopify theme (both the source file and the rendered html)